# JavaScript Objects using this keyword

Tags: javascript, object, this

I'm currently working on some practice for JavaScript and am really confused about what I am to do here. Any help would be appreciated!

**Define a method named orderOfAppearance() that takes the name of a role as an argument and returns that role's order of appearance. If the role is not found, the method returns 0. Ex: orderOfAppearance("Elizabeth Swann") returns 3. Hint: A method may access the object's properties using the keyword this. Ex: this.title accesses the object's title property.**

```
 // Code will be tested with different roles and movies
let movie = { 
   title: "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End",
   director: "Gore Verbinski",
   composer: "Hans Zimmer",
   roles: [ // Roles are stored in order of appearance
      "Jack Sparrow",
      "Will Turner",
      "Elizabeth Swann",
      "Hector Barbossa"
   ],
   orderOfAppearance: function(role) {

      /* Your solution goes here */
      if (!(role in this.roles)) {
         return 0;
      }
      return this.role;
      /*Solution ends here */
   }
};
```

Comment: "not to use a field named last(tail) in our program" Can you call it something else? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: No you are simply not allowed to have a variable that holds the value of the last node. My TA said you have to use first(head) to access the value of last(tail)

Answer (score 1):

> If the role is not found, the method returns 0. Ex: orderOfAppearance("Elizabeth Swann") returns 3.

You can use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the index of the role passed to the `orderOfAppearance()` method and then add 1 to it. `.indexOf()` will return -1 if the role is not found and it will become 0 after adding 1.

```js
let movie = {
  title: "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End",
  director: 'Gore Verbinski',
  composer: 'Hans Zimmer',
  roles: ['Jack Sparrow', 'Will Turner', 'Elizabeth Swann', 'Hector Barbossa'],
  orderOfAppearance: function(role) {
    return this.roles.indexOf(role) + 1
  },
}

console.log(movie.orderOfAppearance('Jack Sparrow'))
console.log(movie.orderOfAppearance('Will Turner'))
console.log(movie.orderOfAppearance('Elizabeth Swann'))
console.log(movie.orderOfAppearance('Hector Barbossa'))
console.log(movie.orderOfAppearance('Something that does not exist in roles'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A doubly linked list has 2 links. Let's use common sense for a moment instead of blind deferral to whatever you think your TA said: "Doubly linked list" obviously implies "2 links", otherwise that'd be an extremely silly name, no?

So, there must be 2 links. You seem to be under the impression that 'you must not have a pointer to the tail' implies 'there must be only one link'. That can't be right, what with 'doubly linked list' and all.

The right answer is presumably that each node has 2 links, but these links aren't 'head and tail', but 'next' and 'previous'.

For a ringed list (where moving forward from the last element gets you back to the first, and moving backwards from the first element gets you to the last), the last node's "next" link goes back to the first node, and conversely, the first node's "previous" link goes to the last (so it points at the same thing a hypothetical 'tail' would point to).

However, that'd be only true for the first node in your linked list structure (that would be the only node for which 'prev' points at the tail).

Your TA either means 'have next/prev links, not next/tail links' as per above, or has no idea what they are talking about. Let's give em the benefit of the doubt ;) – as it's homework I'll leave the actual writing of the data structure, using a definition of `DoublyLinkedNode<T>` that includes fields `DoublyLinkedNode<T> next, prev;`, as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was to refer to the last use first.getPrev(), since its a circle the last is before the first.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. This is found in a zybooks online textbook. The textbook's portion of JavaScript is horrible!! It explains little about what we need to do to solve the questions posed. I have been so frustrated and had to look to online sources to try to solve the problems in the book. Was there a solution to this question?

**Define a method named orderOfAppearance() that takes the name of a role as an argument and returns that role's order of appearance. If the role is not found, the method returns 0.** Ex: orderOfAppearance("Elizabeth Swann") returns 3. Hint: A method may access the object's properties using the keyword this. Ex: this.title accesses the object's title property.

```
// Code will be tested with different roles and movies
   let movie = { 
   title: "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End",
   director: "Gore Verbinski",
   composer: "Hans Zimmer",
   roles: [ // Roles are stored in order of appearance
         "Jack Sparrow",
         "Will Turner",
         "Elizabeth Swann",
         "Hector Barbossa"
          ],
orderOfAppearance: function(role) {
\\your solution goes here
  return this.roles;
 }
};
```

I entered return this.roles; but everything else in the code came from the computer. the answer comes up wrong and says:

Testing orderOfAppearance("Elizabeth Swann")
Yours and expected differ. See highlights below.

Yours
Jack Sparrow,Will Turner,Elizabeth Swann,Hector Barbossa

Expected
3

I also entered:

return this.roles[3]

but that gives Hector Barbossa. I don't know what to do!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30475750)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok thanks. I am new to this site.